# ms sql commit failed, rollback not complete

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jboss7.x, jta

I have a parent and child table in MS SQL 2008 and trying to perform a save call using hibernate with cascade enabled.
Table specs that matter: parent table has an identity column and child table has a varchar column with length 50.

Environment: spring,jboss 7.1.1, hibernate 3, jta transaction (transaction is started/commited/rolled back from the code by obtaining the transaction from jndi)

Issue Arises when: the data that i insert in the child table varchar column is more than 50.

The insert query on the child table is fired only when i execute commit, and it fails to insert because of the char length. I get an exception because of this, i catch the exception and perform a rollback, rollback fails because the transaction is in inactive state.

Issue: The problem here is the parent data is getting committed which is not what I want. How to make sure that the transaction is rolled back completely?

Comment: Can you post your code? The sole purpose of transactions is to prevent what you are seeing, so most likely you are using the jndi transaction incorrectly.

Comment: Can you share some more info? What is the contents of the exception? Do you have an example of your save/rollback code? What does your INSERT code look like?